# Fragments onOptionsItemSelected

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-menu, fragment-backstack

How can i make the `fragments` on the `backstack` not to trigger the `onOptionsItemSelected()`. Because every time i create a new `fragment` it always trigger the `onOptionsItemSelected()` if i select an item in `menu`. Also this `fragment` will be reused throughout the `activity` so "return true" on `onOptionsItemSelected()`  is not an option because the `fragment` that was created still the same with the `backstack` fragment.

Comment: Please, post you code of menu (XML) of several fragments. Do they use a single menu? If not, are menu items have the same ID's in different menus?

Comment: Hi there, yes the fragments only uses single menu

Answer (score 1):

It appears that onOptionsItemSelected will always be called in every new fragment that is added in activity [Menu documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html) [image], so to solve my problem is that I added a validation which appears this one 
*<**CurrentFragment**>this.equals(fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.frame_container)* to validate if the fragment displayed/ attached in activity is the fragment that trigger the onOptionsItemSelected.

Hope this will help to anyone who will have this kind of behaviour on fragments.